# prove or disprove that $-(x^{-1})=(-x)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this equality which attempting proof of the equality $|x/y|=|x|/|y|$. Please help me prove that  $-(x^{-1})=(-x)^{-1}$

Comment: Did you mean $-(x^{-1})=(-x)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes i exactly mean that

Comment: If $x$ has a multiplicative inverse, then the product $(-x)\cdot [-(x^{-1})] = \ldots$.

Comment: @peterwhy . got it. So it proceed this way.

Comment: $$ $(-x)[-(x^{-1})]=xx^{-1} =1 \implies (-x)^{-1}(-x)[-(x^{-1})]=(-x)^{-1} \implies [-(x^{-1})]=(-x)^{-1}$ $$

Answer (score 2):

$(-x)^{-1}=(-1)^{-1}x^{-1}=-1x^{-1}=-(x^{-1})$